# Microsoft Graph API & Teams - Cannot add User to Microsoft Teams Group

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We have setup a routine with a customer that would allow us to add new members to a team:

- An account is created for us on the customer's tenant
- The permission groupmember.readwrite.all is delegated by the account to our application
- The account is Owner of a specific Microsoft Teams team
- We fetch the list of groups and filter by the name of the team we want: GET `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=displayName eq '{subteam_name}'` - Works OK
- We find the identifier of the group - OK
- We make a request to add the user to the group: POST `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<group_id>/members/$ref`with body: `{ "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user_email>" }`

In the last step, we receive a 403:

```
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-09-16T13:24:48",
            "request-id": "f18ad771-0add-46d8-b759-e943245859c9",
            "client-request-id": "f18ad771-0add-46d8-b759-e943245859c9"
        }
    }
}
```

This does not make sense:

- We have the correct scope. We know it has been given to us otherwise listing groups would not be possible
- The user is part of the tenant and can be found on the tenant by the account provided to us
- The account is Owner of the team

We have tested this on our tenant and have had no issues with our implementation. What could be going wrong?

Comment: Could you please check permissions in auth token using [JWT.io](https://jwt.io/)

Comment: This tool is awesome! The scope is "scp": "Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared GroupMember.ReadWrite.All Mail.Read profile openid email" so it includes the desired scope

Comment: To add members to team you need permissions TeamMember.ReadWrite.All but it is missing in your token. Could you please try adding the required permissions? Check this docs for [more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post-members?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions)

Comment: This is a /beta endpoint, it seems preferrable to use it. Isn't a Teams team classified as a group in Microsoft Graph? I can find the group when listing groups, if I have the GroupMember.ReadWrite.All permission why wouldn't I be able to add the user to the group?

Comment: I meant not to use it*

Comment: Additionally, using the endpoint you provided means a new implementation to work on for us. I am pretty certain this should be doable using the scope I provided and the method I provided, since I was able to test it in our pre-production environment, using the scope described only. I'm wondering why it wouldn't work on our customer's tenant.

Comment: Currently we can add member using beta APi  only. Add member api is not available in V1.0.

Comment: I've implemented the endpoint you provided.
POST /teams/{teamsId}/members  
```{
@odata.type: '#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember', 
roles: [
'member'
], 
user@odata.bind: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<user_email>
}```

We received a 404 user not found. Do you know what the issue could be? This works fine on our tenant, but I feel like it may be an issue with identifying the user through their email.

Comment: I've been told the reason is that we are not trying to add the user based on their UPN but on their email. The issue is that it's going to be tough figuring out the UPN with the scopes we have... Would you happen to have any idea on this or are we going to have to ask for another scope? :'(

Comment: The user email will not work for the endpoint, You need to provide the UPN. that is by design